# строки в алфавите,си

Tags: c

Помогите, написал программу чтобы сортировать строку по алфавиту. Как можно переделать, чтобы строка была вводимая, голова уже не варит.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void sort(char **words,int size) {

    int n,m,code;
    char *temp;
    for(n=1; n<size; n++)
        for(m=0; m<size-n; m++) {
            code=strcmp(words[m],words[m+1]);
            if(code>0) {
                temp=words[m];
                words[m]=words[m+1];
                words[m+1]=temp;
            }
        }

    for (n = 0; n < size; n++)
        printf("%s ",words[n] );


}


int main() {
    char *words []= {"fake","bus","atom"};

    int size =sizeof(words)/sizeof(char*);
    sort(words,size);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Напимер так

```
char str[80];

/* в переменную str считывается не более 79 символов */
scanf("%79s", str);
```

Comment: так не получится

Comment: @Артем ну не str, так words